# Impedance of a Dickson Multiplier

Tags: rf, impedance, multiplier, charge-pump

Can someone help me in regards to calculating the impedance of a Dickson multiplier?

It consists of capacitors of 3.3 pF and 2850 shottky diodes. They can be assumed ideal. It consists of 7 stages, followed by a load consisting of a capacitor of 100pf and a resistor of 499 ohm.

[image: circuit of such a Dickson multiplier, powered by an AC Source (specifically a patch antenna)]

The resistance of the load resisitor is 499 ohm, not 499k ohm

Comment: Impedance will vary with frequency. Did you have any frequency in mind?

Comment: My Antenna is resonant at about 2.1 ghz.

Comment: This doesn't look like a Dickson charge pump.  It look more like a Cockcroft-Walton voltage multiplier.  The Dickson charge pump has a fixed DC input and uses two out of phase clock signals to multiply the DC. You don't have a fixed DC source, and you only have one RF signal.

Comment: @JRE -- I built a Dickson like this in LTSpice, and am getting >80% effic with a bipolar h-bridge driving it. The differentiation is capacitors in parallel for Dickson, and capacitors in series for Cockroft-Walton. This is definitely Dickson.

Answer (score 2):

This design will fail miserably with the capacitance of diodes greater than 3.3p and microwave f input being unrealistic as well as the 500k load too much for the very low series capacitance that is daisy-chained.

There are very real theoretical limitations to the maximum theoretical number of cascades and that reduces when you add a load.  Adding each stage reduces the series impedance of the cap added to the previous. Charging current available thus reduces.

So in theory for an input Vp sine wave ideal voltage source, the array of 2 series and 1 parallel caps for each stage has an input impedance = Xc.eq=(Xc/2) // Xc) and a maximum DC voltage gain of 2n is attenuated by the impedance ratio of Zout/(Zin+Zout).  As Zout rises the charge rise time decays and reaches a terminal voltage of only $$Vout=Vpp*(n)$$ with no load with input Vpp and n stages.

When loaded, you no longer achieve full peak voltage as the sag between pulse reduces due to the impedance ratio of R/(R/Xc(f)) for the output cap.  It may take several thousand cycles to reach 99% of the peak voltage.  Diode capacitance will act as a voltage divider which reduces the gain further. For larger e-caps the series ESR becomes an attenuating factor.

Thus for 10 stages with Vpp = 30V, open load Vol = 330V Vpp and with a 1M load drops to 300Vdc or \$10/11 *V_{ol}\$   with 100k load it drops to 200Vdc or $20/33 * V_{ol}.

So what is the output impedance that causes this **load regulation error** drop in %?

[This simulates your circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgLCDMB0CMBMBWApgWlrE8z2gBkjAA5ZIA2PeAdnlLKxFkXEQCgATKReEKvCMJB58IPdsgBmAQwCuAGwAurAMZceZbOCEgNEPFGjwAnCdNmzVNAhCpIVaIgSQmBR-yKEQefHlgct6pqOgaIg4tLySqrBOkHWIl4GxuYpJpboPGCI0EREVLB4iEZUxHaQRF4%20fgDuAbxEEDEJeKwA5mr1EJDcIER4%20gOsAEodulD8sXqMjP2zs4zMA5VsnN3CDR0JYpKyiv6CwhMHkwzhu1F1CcdUG-owyanm6dbwuEZ4HmAYiI7FREY8bz9PyqNYnMHNJKPFLPHjoMAOMgkWBUOxkSB4MhGLGVYH%20GJjGKIMChM6RFQgIo8YmNAEnO6GaFPKzqIjQIyEIxgLkEbnWIG%20fHWGmUuki7YRPaqMg0SkknSysBkKb3JkWFk2AH4IgaYlkDCEPKAqoU44ionyhkPNWwmwUaB8vBUIxEYlURBIxYm2pgsZmy2sWr%20xrWJV6CkxMOizLKxKqtVpDWoDwOcoAoSfApfXGCzhU8CxmUx0k7cl5sXy-NRiXnfxGF6aes8WDymvk1QmZvyztYTRWhOJjKMHUOyivJUY-WCPQmzhNxjduktkuSi4eLsQefLuOMge29BUexZyDkdH8H59k2qd08ce9bR3-t7pNMGCCLnEf5ML5UegCvycOuvabg2K61h2oEgPOGIqruCa2rAGgOP05DUIghTkC2OYAfePAwbhwGnKWUrRlAGxFmRsHWky%204FGQ0BYmODRNki%20TYRSN6UbwPRRk%208Eat80B2I4NBgP0DRYkY7GcJx5QQLJExtnsnAUVGFFyURq4UkB%20E6bcULPkOpBsh4broRgurENJ3F4RMOmKWExEXOpEwKVRA7FC%20xjss6LYaH0v7oX%20s4KnhGyyRsSkXD2sbzrGfE2hq8C%20D4%20oum4iAnlJ-4Ugg-Q2IhjDJfo8WMFY%20jwHYjLIiQiA0IhTDsaoBSyrGLUbju1HQratDeHVlUUCSsDFOQ1ntToEDjeg9BRXWS6LuoYHtlBdLTTMsprQlNFJq82QouihBCMNhQ3NZMWTU6i2abWtT5hpLnhrd8QTPmYwtLUD02YR72kWMFEij9nF3kB24-XpIG2Y9UHWLFq2FT90ETD2j6BgR25xVDnFRuDXio-98pY-FqPI5o42g6jkaxndtyowgfTgBUFkVBpP1k-K3xXazTBXXlJVQ7zE1Fdigus8VBX0AgwtrfAqPXBsEI02JkBQRQHSwH0FQeks%20oAPoFNgOt4Hrk5kDrxjeACRQysS9YFCihs%20L4htmzruuQP4U2FQL0uOVpABOQt-oHIszHMrAAM7B2tktB-omDSHI4fIKwQA) but is very suboptimal for generating HV.

Consider better f, C and impedances for the array of 2 series and 1 parallel caps = Ceq=(C/2n+Cn)

Comment: Thank you very much, the actual resistance of the resistor is 499 ohm, not 499 k

Comment: That’s not going to work. Try 10M or 3.3 nF

Answer (score 0):

If your simulation runs, you can measure it.  You specified \$V\$, measure \$I\$ then calculate \$R\$ using ohms law.

$$R=\frac{V}{I}$$

As Brian points out in his comment, it will vary with frequency.  So the method I've shown will only work for one frequency at a time.  It doesn't give insight into the impedance as\$f\$ changes unless you do multiple runs.

Comment: but what is V for this design?  Not very much

Comment: It looks like the V is set to 1V.

Comment: Even if in theory it is 10V it wont work. Explain why

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I agree that 2.2GHz is probably just going to flow through those diodes like they are caps.  BUT, I wasn't analysing the OP circuit for operation, I just answered the OPs question, which is how to get the input impedance.  The provided circuit still has an input impedance regardless of how well it functions.

Comment: That applies to DC but is too simple to be accurate here